# Combine pandas df colums and rows to get a pairs in a string - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is my df:

```py
d = {'Equipment': ['A','B','C'], 'Downtime': [3,8, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

i would like to create a string that looks like `(A,3);(B,8);(C,4)`

even better would be :

`(Equipment:A,Downtime:3);(Equipment:B,Downtime:8);(Equipment:C,Downtime:4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `df.apply` and `str.join`:

```
print(
    ";".join(
        df.apply(
            lambda x: "("
            + ",".join(
                "{}:{}".format(name, value) for name, value in zip(x.index, x)
            )
            + ")",
            axis=1,
        ).values
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
(Equipment:A,Downtime:3);(Equipment:B,Downtime:8);(Equipment:C,Downtime:4)
```

---

EDIT: To get output in DataFrame:

```
x = ";".join(
    df.apply(
        lambda x: "("
        + ",".join(
            "{}:{}".format(name, value) for name, value in zip(x.index, x)
        )
        + ")",
        axis=1,
    ).values
)
df_out = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": x}])
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                                                Name
0  (Equipment:A,Downtime:3);(Equipment:B,Downtime...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I am new to Python, but is it possible to get the print output as a data frame with one column, and all the content of the print will just be one string row value

column Name:
(Equipment:A,Downtime:3);(Equipment:B,Downtime:8);(Equipment:C,Downtime:4)

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot